# Formatted output from a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create a ticket for a game of Housie and want the output to be as below from a list of numbers

```
input_list = [[14, 15, 17, 26, 31], [36, 41, 42, 43, 62], [67, 75, 85, 87, 92]]
```

Output:

```
| 14 | 15 | 17 | 26 | 31 |

| 36 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 62 |

| 67 | 75 | 85 | 87 | 92 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for e in input_list:
    print('|', '|'.join(map(str, e)), '|', sep='')
    print() # remove this if you don't need an empty line after each row
```

Above code iterates through all elements in the list and formats each one individually. First, one `|` is printed. After that, elements of the upper level loop's element are joined in the strings (`'|'.join` means that `|` will be used to separate elements). And for the end, another `|` is printed.

Comment: Simpler: `print('', *e, '', sep='|')`

Comment: Really nice one!